# Rails: Relation does not exist for reference with class name in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I created two references in a migration that are aliases for a reference to my User table:

```
class CreateInvitations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.references :owner, references: :user, foreign_key: true # the owner
      t.references :invitee, references: :user, foreign_key: true # the invitee
      t.references :core_bot, foreign_key: true # the associated page (core_bot_active)
      t.string :email
      t.string :token

      t.timestamps

    end
  end
end
```

In my User model:

```
  has_many :invitations, foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many :invitations, foreign_key: :invitee_id, dependent: :destroy
```

In my Invitation model:

```
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: :User
  belongs_to :invitee, class_name: :User
```

Everything works well in development but when I try to migrate in production with Heroku `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I get the following error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "owners" does not exist : CREATE
>   TABLE "invitations" ("id" serial primary key, "owner_id" integer,
>   "invitee_id" integer, "core_bot_id" integer, "email" character
>   varying, "token" character varying, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
>   "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_59e24979a9"
>   FOREIGN KEY ("owner_id")   REFERENCES "owners" ("id") , CONSTRAINT
>   "fk_rails_00204dc74b" FOREIGN KEY ("invitee_id")   REFERENCES
>   "invitees" ("id") , CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_34505bdb65" FOREIGN KEY
>   ("core_bot_id")   REFERENCES "core_bots" ("id") )

I tried without `references: :user` but I get the same error.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your development is probably an sqLite database but Heroku uses PostgreSQL and the interpretation of the migration is generating a foregn key to `owners`

Write the migration like this instead...

```
class CreateInvitations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.references :owner, index: true # the owner
      t.references :invitee, index: true # the invitee
      t.references :core_bot, foreign_key: true # the associated page (core_bot_active)
      t.string :email
      t.string :token

      t.timestamps

    end
    add_foreign_key :invitations, :users, column: :owner_id
    add_foreign_key :invitations, :users, column: :invitee_id
  end
end
```

It's one of the risks with developing using a different database product than the production implementation. Migrations may not work exactly the same. If planning to deploy to Heroku you should look at using postgreSQL in development.

Answer (score 1):

I don't how to fix your problem. But I allways creating migrations for Postgres DB with foreign keys like this:

```
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.integer :owner_id
      t.integer :invitee_id
      t.references :core_bot, foreign_key: true # the associated page (core_bot_active)
      t.string :email
      t.string :token

      t.timestamps    
    end
    add_index :invitations, :owner_id 
    add_foreign_key :invitations, :users, column: :owner_id
    add_index :invitations, :invitee_id 
    add_foreign_key :invitations, :users, column: :invitee_id
  end
```

Comment: Thank you it works! I accept the answer of Steve as he gives a bit more details about the difference of database used. ;)

Answer (score -1):

try removing foreign_key: true from the options, since we are giving it a references, I think we don't need a foreign_key: true option

```
class CreateInvitations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.references :owner, # the owner
      t.references :invitee, # the invitee
      t.references :core_bot # the associated page (core_bot_active)
      t.string :email
      t.string :token

      t.timestamps

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think it would be the answer because you are not creating the FK on the `invitations` table. And that will cause that the validation is going to be only on the ORM layer but not at a DB level and data could be inconsistent. You should also add the corresponding FK and Indexes manually, something like this:
```add_foreign_key :invitations, :users, column: :owner_id```
```add_foreign_key :invitations, :users, column: :invitee_id```
```add_index :invitations, :owner_id```
```add_index :invitations, :invitee_id```